# Qt build warning: directory '/tmp/qt-stuff-6474/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/lib' following -L not found

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to get a Qt app compiling for Mac running Snow Leopard, using Qt Creator 2.0.1 and Qt 4.7.0 (64 bit).

The app compiles on other platforms, but on my Mac I get this warning

> :: warning: directory
>   '/tmp/qt-stuff-6474/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/lib'
>   following -L not found

This is a new install of Qt Creator, and the .pro file contains no references to this directory.

What causes this warning, and how might I correct it?

Comment: How did you install Qt itself? With the prebuilt binaries or from the source? The error looks like the build process from the source is not complete.

Comment: prebuilt - installed from the currently available Mac binaries (qt-sdk-mac-opensource-2010.05.dmg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is visible here on the bugtracker:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13462

Answer (score 0):

It's only a warning. It's not going to stop the build unless you are using gcc and compiling with '-Werror' (Check your CFLAGS).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a glitch in the prebuilt 4.7.0 package for Mac - I see the exact same message. As other people mentioned, it's only a warning - ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Tested workaround:
In the Terminal execute next commands

```
cd /
perl -pi -e 's,-F/tmp/qt-stuff-\d+/source/qt-everywhere-\w+-src-\d\.\d\.\d/lib,,g' `find /Library/Frameworks -name *.prl`
perl -pi -e 's,-L/tmp/qt-stuff-\d+/source/qt-everywhere-\w+-src-\d\.\d\.\d/lib,,g' `find /Library/Frameworks -name *.prl`
```